# Informix SQL - ORDER BY BLOB

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, blob, informix

Is there a way to sort by BLOB-type (TEXT) column?

The direct attempt leads to an error:

> "Blobs are not allowed in the 'order by' clause."

Loading all data and sorting using Java doesn't seem to be a good idea, as the DB is large.

Attempt to cast BLOB to VARCHAR:

```
CAST(blob_column AS varchar)
```

leads to an error:

> No cast from text to varchar.

SUBSTRING(status_message from 1 for 50) or SUBSTR(status_message, 1, 50) also leads to an error:

> Blobs are not allowed in this expression.

Comment: I'd try `order by substring(blob_column from 1 for 50)`.

Comment: I don't think `substring` would accept a `TEXT` argument